# Creating nested if + else if statements but function comes back as undefined

Tags: javascript

I am having problems with this code and the console states that the function is not defined. I can't seem to understand why though.

```
<script>
    var month = new Date();
    var current_month = month.getMonth();
    var monthlist = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
    var YOY = 11;
    var org_traffic = 1,256;
    var HD = 12;
    var VIN = 30;
    var emails = 20;
    function analysis() {
        if (YOY >= 10) {
            if (HD >= 5) {
                if (VIN >= 5) {
                    if (emails >= 5) {
                        document.write("This month we saw that overall organic traffic has improved "+YOY+"% compared to last year, bringing in a total of "+org_traffic+" visits in "+(monthlist[current_month - 1])+", accompanied by the growth we're seeing with H&D visits, VIN views, and email leads!");
                    }
                    else {
                        document.write("This month we saw that overall organic traffic has improved "+YOY+"% compared to last year, bringing in a total of "+org_traffic+" visits in "+(monthlist[current_month - 1])+", accompanied by the growth we're seeing with H&D visits,and VIN views!");
                    } 
                }
                else if (VIN >= 0) {
                    document.write("This month we saw that overall organic traffic has improved "+YOY+"% compared to last year, bringing in a total of "+org_traffic+" visits in "+(monthlist[current_month - 1])+", accompanied by the growth we're seeing with H&D visits!<br/>We do see a modest "+VIN+"% growth in VIN views, which I'll be aiming to improve over the coming quarter.");
                }
                else if (VIN <= 0) {
                    document.write("This month we saw that overall organic traffic has improved "+YOY+"% compared to last year, bringing in a total of "+org_traffic+" visits in "+(monthlist[current_month - 1])+", accompanied by the growth we're seeing with H&D visits!<br/>Unfortuntately we did see a decrease in VIN views by about "+VIN+"%, which I'll be aiming to improve over the coming quarter.");
                }
                }
            else {
                document.write("This month we saw that overall organic traffic has improved "+YOY+"% compared to last year, bringing in a total of "+org_traffic+" visits in "+(monthlist[current_month - 1])+". Unfortunately our engagement metircs don't seem to be following suit and therefore will become a major focus of mine moving forward to turn our growing traffic numbers into an engaged visitor base.");
            }
            }
        else if (YOY >= 0) {
            document.write("This month we saw a modest "+YOY+"% growth in overall organic traffic compared to last year, bringing in a total of "+org_traffic+" visits. While any growth is definitely a positive, I would like to see this number improve over the coming quarter and will be taking proactive steps to turn up the dial on this trend.");
        }
        else if (YOY <= 0) {
            document.write("This month we saw a decrease in overall organic traffic compared to year by -"+YOY+"%. This is definitely not the trend I am looking to see from our efforts on the website. I'll be conducting a thorough investigation to see what factors may be causing this downward trend. I'll be sure to keep you up to date as I dig deeper into the root cause of this trend.");
        }
    }
    document.write(analysis());
    </script>
```

I'd love any suggestions that I may try to make this function properly.

Comment: You never return anything on the function. Having `document.write(analysis())` is not necessary, just use `analysis()`.

Comment: Use `return "This month we saw...."` instead of `document.write(...)`. You allready write the response from `analysis`. That way it is easier to use the output for something else than `document.write`

Comment: There is no need to call your method within `document.write(analysis());`. Simply call it by itself `analysis()`; The code inside will perform the `document.write();`

Comment: read about nested coding horror and try to flatten your statement. that would be the "right" way

Comment: @Alex that, and if you're going to have that many conditionals you might want to leave a comment inside of them explaining what the condition means... and the variables could use some more descriptive names.

Comment: And while looking at it again you have another problem/semantic-issue. if `(YOY >= 10) { first; } else if (YOY >= 0) { second; }`  second can logically not happen.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a comma `var org_traffic = 1,256;` should be `var org_traffic = 1256;`

Fix that invalid assignment, and then the code wont' break before hitting your function definition. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is some weird stuff going on.

Your comma in `var org_traffic = 1, 256` does not belong there.

Your function does not return a string, so you just call `analysis()` and not write the function, because the functions return value is `undefined`.

And console will always log `undefined` for `document.write()`, because it has no return value, too.